# FingerPrint cannot work in Service

Tags: android, fingerprint

I try to using FingerPrint API  to build a demo,like this:

```
        if (fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

            // start fingerprint auth here.
            try {
                //                    CryptoObjectHelper cryptoObjectHelper = new CryptoObjectHelper();


                if (cancellationSignal == null) {
                    cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

                }

                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
                }


                myAuthCallback = new MyAuthCallback(context, handler);



                fingerprintManager.authenticate(null, cancellationSignal, 0, myAuthCallback, null);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
```

and it works in an Activity Component,I can distinguish my fingerprints.
But when I try to using these codes working with a Service or a BroadcastReciver Component, I cannot receive any callback,is it right that FingerPrint API can use in Activity Component only ?why is that?

Comment: You need to show a UI to user to tell him to put his finger, and you could start activity from your service

Comment: I use a floating view created by service to tell user to put his finger .The question is>>                                                                 fingerprintManager.authenticate(null, cancellationSignal, 0, myAuthCallback, null);>>I get nothing about the result if I use these codes in service,but it works in Activity ,I want to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the answer from the source code,

/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/fingerprint/Fingerprint/FingerprintService.java

```
      @Override // Binder call
      public void authenticate(final IBinder token, final long opId, final int groupId,
              final IFingerprintServiceReceiver receiver, final int flags,
              final String opPackageName) {
          if (!canUseFingerprint(opPackageName, true /* foregroundOnly */)) {
              if (DEBUG) Slog.v(TAG, "authenticate(): reject " + opPackageName);
              return;
         }

                ……

  private boolean canUseFingerprint(String opPackageName, boolean foregroundOnly) {
      checkPermission(USE_FINGERPRINT);
      final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
      final int pid = Binder.getCallingPid();
      if (opPackageName.equals(mKeyguardPackage)) {
          return true; // Keyguard is always allowed
      }
      if (!isCurrentUserOrProfile(UserHandle.getCallingUserId())) {
          Slog.w(TAG,"Rejecting " + opPackageName + " ; not a current       user or profile");
          return false;
      }
      if (mAppOps.noteOp(AppOpsManager.OP_USE_FINGERPRINT, uid, opPackageName)
              != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
          Slog.w(TAG, "Rejecting " + opPackageName + " ; permission denied");
          return false;
      }
      if (foregroundOnly && !isForegroundActivity(uid, pid)) {
          Slog.w(TAG, "Rejecting " + opPackageName + " ; not in foreground");
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }


  private boolean isForegroundActivity(int uid, int pid) {
      try {
          List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procs =
                  ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().getRunningAppProcesses();
          int N = procs.size();
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
              RunningAppProcessInfo proc = procs.get(i);
              if (proc.pid == pid && proc.uid == uid
                      && proc.importance == IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
          Slog.w(TAG, "am.getRunningAppProcesses() failed");
      }
      return false;
  }
```

It is asked for a foreground activity to authenticate!!